# UML-diagraming a plugin architecture

Tags: uml

I want to show that in my new system, plugins are used to control the core software components.

What would be a good way to show that in UML? I will definitely use sequence diagrams to show interactions between the core and the plugins, but is there some sort of static diagram that fits?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose a simple Component Model with assembly links and references back to the underlying system requirements.

I'd also give an indication as to how the plug-ins are instantiated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a class diagram you could show an abstract plugin interface IPlugin and a bunch of concrete (imaginary) plugin implementations like Controller1, Controller2, Example3 etc. From that diagram it should be obvious that you can extend the system. If your plugins are physical components (like separate files), then a deployment diagram can be used as well.